# Should the salary pay date be mentioned on offer letter or appointment letter?

Tags: salary, job-offer, india, legal

I had asked my H.R. to mention the salary pay date on my offer letter or the appointment letter.
He said that no organization does it. I want to know are the companies SUPPOSED to (legally) mention the date of payment for every month?

The reason I had asked this is that the company does not pay on the expected date which is normally agreed upon, usually, 10th of every month. They delay it a month or so. Ex-employees claim they have not been paid for more than 2 to 5 months period.

This concerned me. Does a verbal agreement of a screenshot of chat work as evidence in case things go south?

Comment: For questions about legalities, you should mention the country/jurisdiction. Laws tend to be different around the world 

Comment: I reside in India @Hans-MartinMosner

Comment: Thank you for editing the question to a more readable format. @Sourav Ghosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am from India, and I have never seen salary payout date to be mentioned in the offer letter.

It is usually mentioned as "last working day of the month" or something along that line, in the joining form that you fill on the day of joining (but that's also nothing standard, it's a part of company policies and once you're an employee, you have access to those policy documents. Not sure if anyone would like to have them accessed by a non-employee, i.e., general public) - but I have never seen it to be mentioned in the offer or appointment letter.

IANAL, so cannot really answer from the legality aspect, but the bigger problem here is:

> *ex-employees claim they have not been paid for more than 2 to 5 months period.*

If you know (and trust those reviews) that the company has a poor reputation, why are you interested in the offer anyways? On the other hand, if this is the ONLY choice you've got, you kind of have to compromise on the payout date, illegal or otherwise.

Finally,

- verbal agreement means **nothing**, and
- exposing screenshot of a private chat will land you into more trouble than solving one for you.

Better way is to have an email acceptance of whatever the discussion is, as and when possible.

Comment: does slack chat on their own channel count as private chat?
thanks for the explanation, scenarios due to covid have pushed to these statuses

Comment: @YashTibrewal Yes, unless it's on a public platform, it's private and confidential info.